# SQL Server CE database doesn't get update before copy the database file

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm creating an application in C# using SQL Server CE which in a part I need to update a record in a table and then copy the database file a different address.

This is the code:

```
RSSql.UpdateNonQueryParametric("update tblSetFromClient set  LocxExit=?,LocyExit=?" +
                                           " where IDSetFromClient=" + Global.IdSetFormClient, Exit.Location.X,Exit.Location.Y);
if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Out\DB\PM.sdf"))
{
    File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + @"\Out\DB\PM.sdf");
}

File.Copy(Application.StartupPath + @"\DB\PM.sdf", Application.StartupPath + @"\Out\DB\PM.sdf");
```

The problem is it will copy the file with the previous values. for example if LocxExit and LocyExit have the values of 200 and I update them with 400, the cloned file still has the value of 200.

So I think the COPY runs faster than UPDATE command.

How can I copy the file after the update actually happens?

Thank you

Comment: Does UpdateNonQueryParametric() at least close the connection?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes it does.